# iframe expand and shrink on hover

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I have a drop down menu for members inside  an iframe.

The size of the iframe depends on variables and would therefore need to be height 100%, width 100% when a users hovers over a button, so any necessary info can be seen.

The iframe needs to go from a height 50px, width:300px to 100%,100%.

This is so that the other parent page links will work when the menu is not in dropdown.

i.e.something like

```
<iframe id="parent".....><ul><li class="drop_item">button1</li><li class="drop_item">button2</div></ul></iframe>
```

"Parent" needs to expand on hover "drop_item".

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The content in the iframe is _fallback_ content, that will only be displayed if the iframe doesn't work. That is, if everything works correctly, the list will never be shown. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: The iframe needs to be a set size so it doesn't impinge on the rest of the page, that is not a problem. It is when the frame needs to expand and then shrink on a hover in and hover out on a button within the frame. All works well if I give it a large height and width but this stops the link on the parent page working.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you got the point of `<iframe>` - iframe is meant to display content from another url within a "box" in your page, it must have a `src` attribue that links to the other page. (as @MrLister said - the content within it's markup is only shown when the browser does not support iframes) You should try using `<div>` instead like this:

```
<div id="parent".....><ul><li class="drop_item">button1</li><li class="drop_item">button2</div></ul></div>
```

And then apply this `CSS` code (no need of `jQuery` in this case):

```
#parent{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
}

#parent:hover{
    width:100%;
    hieght:100%;
}
```

**note that these `CSS` rules should also work if you decide to keep working with the iframe

Comment: Yes I do understand the concept. For technical reasons I am having to src the menu from a framework inside a folder on the same domain.The above would not work for the iframe sine the whole page would become the iframe and there would be no way to hover out to return to the parent page

Comment: then wrap your iframe with a container...? that way 100% won't be the entire screen only then container's size.. (if it's `position:absolute;`? try another approach)

Comment: that's the same as sizing the iframe surely? This also restricts the size of the iframe. Once it is hovered, it will be difficult to hover out because of the size. It needs to be a hover over the buttons within the iframe that dictates the size of it. I can't see how your method can work but if you have an example?

Comment: I strongly suggest you create a jsFiddle of it then I could give the most relevant solution.. I don't know what your code looks like

Comment: I'm using css hover similar to your example at the moment(so no jscript) but this means there is no way to hover out if the frame lies over the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this with iFrame-resizer and a little extra JS.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer#iframe-not-detecting-css-hover-events